# Need some Help Reading File

Tags: c++, file

I need to read a file (not in binary mode). I already have a code to know the size of the file, and what i am searching for is how to read the file by = (the size of the file)-8276 bytes. These bytes that have been read, will be stored in a variable and I will need it to be written.

The size of the file is stored in an unsigned long variable. Can anybody help me?

I use Borland C++

Comment: guys , don't give him negative repo, he's a newbie... instead , provide inputs.. ! Thanks.

Comment: share the code that you have tried , and also mention what kind of issues you are facing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/621425/143897 read the answers to this question

Comment: okay, i'll read it. thanks for @Jay D..

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its been a while since I've touched Borland, so syntax might be off a bit. Consider it pseudocode, but you get the concept.

```
// assuming you've already created the file handle.
HANDLE fileHandle;

unsigned long fileSize;
unsigned long numBytesRead;
bool result;

// get the file size
fileSize = GetFileSize(theFile, NULL);

// check to see if filesize is greater than 8276 bytes.
// if so, read (fileSize - 8276)

if(fileSize >= 8276)
{
result = ReadFile(fileHandle, &objectYouAreReadingItTo, (fileSize - 8276), numBytesRead);
}
else
{
  //...handle when fileSize is less than 8276 bytes...
}
```